# Django-crontab, setting cronjobs

Tags: python, django, docker, cron, django-crontab

I'm currently developing my Django app with various notifications. To avoid frequently querying DB I tried to make cron jobs with an hour intervals, that query for all planed for next hour notifications, count delays, orepare personalized messages etc. For end it should iterate over QuerySet send some tasks to celery queue by apply_async on task.

I am working with django = "==4.2.1", django-crontab = "==0.7.1" and docker-compose.

Whenever I build a container I make a rescheduling of all tasks. By this lines in docker-compose.yml:

```
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      postgres_db:
        condition: service_healthy
      queue:
        condition: service_started
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    command:
      - |
        python manage.py makemigrations
        python manage.py migrate
        python manage.py crontab remove
        python manage.py crontab add
        python manage.py sync_cronjobs
        python manage.py runcrons
        python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.3
LABEL authors="AM"
WORKDIR /app
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock ./

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip &&  \
    pip install --no-cache-dir pipenv &&  \
    pipenv install --dev --system --deploy

RUN apt-get update &&  \
    apt-get install -y cron

COPY . .
```

As a result I have a couple of active crons. The problem is, all works fine when I run cronjobs manually by commands:

```
python manage.py crontab show
Currently active jobs in crontab:
373fcec9cd7d9ec8d95e7cb90d031caf -> ('*/4 * * * *', 'AHC_app.celery_notifications.cron.send_emails')
3a8ed9c92a09c1a2fda1d6342949389d -> ('*/2 * * * *', 'AHC_app.celery_notifications.cron.send_email_example')
0d0751f76f6d5de0ba21d6984ba14cfd -> ('4 * * * *', 'AHC_app.celery_notifications.cron.send_sms')
7926f3cc17e62d57da2eff317a33f1a7 -> ('6 * * * *', 'AHC_app.celery_notifications.cron.send_discord_notes')
python manage.py crontab run 373fcec9cd7d9ec8d95e7cb90d031caf
```

But trying by run all at once without optional argument of hash I get:

```
python manage.py crontab run
<...>
RuntimeError: No job with hash None found. It seems the crontab is out of sync with your settings.CRONJOBS. Run "python manage.py crontab add" again to resolve this issue!
```

And with all active jobs, tasks do not run. I only receive feedback in logs when I run a single job with a command. It ignores the schedule applied in settings.py. Can you lend me some help and advice?

Comment: Where and how are you running those commands?  Generically, a typical setup is to run your main Web server and a cron daemon in two separate containers (and a Celery worker in another if needed); what is arranging for the scheduled jobs to actually be run?  The setup might be simpler if you could arrange your Docker image to not need the `volumes:`, `entrypoint:`, or extended `command:` for routine use.

Comment: In all I have 6 containers:
- django webapp, 
- postgresDB - main,
- couchDB - for files, 
- celery queue,
- redis broker for celery,
- celery-flower.

So, everytime I run them all at one by docker-compose up -d --build.
I run commands in the terminal of main "web" container. The same one, which i passed in the first quote.

Comment: The Celery "stuff" is placed in main Django app, in a package named "app.celery_notofications". Inside it is another package "utils" with tasks, the file config.py that constains Celery config and the cron.py that define jobs that runs by apply_async witch aditional logs. And a level higher is settings.py in which I define CRONJOBS schedule list.